# How To Get Value of Row Table Appended

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have some problems in my code... I am using html and jquery.. 
i want to alert value of **idPredefineDetail** that was appended before... here's my code:

```
<table id="tablePreDefineDetail">
<tr id="rowPreDefineDetail"><td><input type="checkbox" name="chkPredefineDetail" ><input type="hidden" name="idPredefineDetail" value="1"></td><td width="5"><input type="text" name="txtCodePredefineDetail" value="ab"  size="10"></td><td><input type="text" name="txtDescriptionPredefineDetail" id="txtdesk" size="50"></td><td><a href="#"><button class="upPredefine"></button></a><a href="#"><button class="downPredefine"></button></a><a href="#"><button class="removeStdInsBtn"></button></a></td></tr>
<tr id="rowPreDefineDetail"><td><input type="checkbox" name="chkPredefineDetail"  ><input type="hidden" name="idPredefineDetail" value="2"></td><td width="5"><input type="text" name="txtCodePredefineDetail" value="ac"  size="10"></td><td><input type="text" name="txtDescriptionPredefineDetail" id="txtdesk" size="50"></td><td><a href="#"><button class="upPredefine"></button></a><a href="#"><button class="downPredefine"></button></a><a href="#"><button class="removeStdInsBtn"></button></a></td></tr>
</table>
```

When i clicked button remove **removeStdInsBtn**.. i am using the code below:

```
 $('#tablePreDefineDetail tr button.removeStdInsBtn').click(function(e){
    var obj=$(this);
    e.preventDefault();
     $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
          buttons : {
            "Confirm" : function() {

               var idPredefineDetail=$(this).parent().parent().children("input[name=idPredefineDetail]").val();
               alert(idPredefineDetail);
               $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        });

        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
 });
```

anybody help me??

Comment: Don't have duplicate IDs... change `id="rowPreDefineDetail"` to `class="rowPreDefineDetail"`.

Comment: U'd better tell us what's the prob.

Comment: @walio if i alert the value of idPredefineDetail.. the result shown undefined... i don't know how to get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combo of closest and find .
Try this:

```
$('#tablePreDefineDetail tr button.removeStdInsBtn').click(function(e){
    var obj=$(this);
    e.preventDefault();
     $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
          buttons : {
            "Confirm" : function() {

               var idPredefineDetail=obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=idPredefineDetail]").val();
               alert(idPredefineDetail);
               $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        });

        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
 });
```

Comment: In Confirm handler you are using $(this) which refers to the dialog and not the button. You should use obj instead since it is still in scope.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post all your html, but as a first guess, I'd suggest using [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to traverse up the DOM tree.

```
var idPredefineDetail=$(this).closest( "#dialog-confirm" ).children("input[name=idPredefineDetail]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the $(this) is actually pointing to #dialog-confirm. You should use the obj variable that you set at the start of the click callback function. You also didn't go back far enough, you need another parent() call.

```
var idPredefineDetail=obj.parent().parent().parent().children("input[name=idPredefineDetail]").val();
alert(idPredefineDetail);
$(this).dialog("close");
```

Answer (score 0):

well here i want to modify the below mentioned code which was originally posted by Cybernate

$('#tablePreDefineDetail tr button.removeStdInsBtn').click(function(e){   var obj=$(this);

```
e.preventDefault();
 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
           var idPredefineDetail=obj.attr("id");
           alert(idPredefineDetail);
           $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {

          $(this).dialog("close");
        }

      }

    });

    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
```

});

for example i have a hyperlink like this.

clickme

when i click this link the value which i access is id='clickit' as obj.attr("id"); is used.
so we can place a required value in id, or in name or in another tag property and later we can easily acces it...